# How to link to local post

Tags: links

I am creating a post and would like to link to other post on my blog. What is the best way to do this? I don't want to hard link in case I update the post title. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the ugly link instead of the pretty link. For example, if your post id is 123, you can link to http://www.yoursite.com/?p=123. This will automatically get rewritten to your current pretty permalink.

If you do it relative from the root, it also keeps the link intact if you change your domain name. (ex. href="/?p=123").

To find the post ID, hover over its "edit" link in the WordPress admin. Look at the target URL, and you'll see a "post=1234". The number is your post ID.

Comment: How is it rewritten to current pretty permalink?

Answer (score 2):

Use a shortcode. I’ve made one for the same reason in my [shortcode plugin](https://github.com/toscho/WordPress-Shortcodes).

### Usage

Install the plugin [Simply Show IDs](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simply-show-ids/) to find the post IDs. Insert a shortcode into your posts that refers to the ID:

```
[link id=42 title="Foo" class="bar"]Hello World![/link]
```